# Парсер расписания

Tags: php, парсер

Друзья, нужна Ваша помощь!

Подскажите, как спарсить данные со страницы http://www.gosugamers.net/hearthstone/gosubet !
Пробовал обычным `simple_html_dom` - выдает ошибки:

> Warning:
> file_get_contents(http://www.gosugamers.net/dota2/gosubet)
> [function.file-get-contents]: failed
> to open stream: HTTP request failed!
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
> /hosting/parse/test_p.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> find() on a non-object in
> /hosting/parse/test_p.php on line 30

10 строка: `$html = file_get_contents('http://www.gosugamers.net/hearthstone/gosubet');`
30 строка: `foreach($upcoming->find('tr') as $aGame) {`

Ребят, помогите примерчиком, парсящим хоть что-нибудь с данной страницы...
Спасибо огромное!

Полный код на всякий случай:

```
    <?php   
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 
  ini_set ('display_errors', 1);

require_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

  date_default_timezone_set("CET");

  $html = file_get_contents('http://www.gosugamers.net/hearthstone/gosubet');
  $matchList = new simple_html_dom();
  $matchList->load($html);
  $titleList = new simple_html_dom();
  $gameArray = array();
  $output = array();
  $done = $matchList->find('.matches', 2);
  if ($done) {
    $d0 = 0;
    $d1 = 1;
    $d2 = 2;
    $live = true;
  } else {
    $d0 = 0;
    $d1 = 0;
    $d2 = 1;
    $live = false;
  }  
  $upcoming = $matchList->find('#col1 > .box', 1); 
  $game = null;
  foreach($upcoming->find('tr') as $aGame) { 
    $linkID = "http://www.gosugamers.net".$aGame->find('a', 0)->href;
    $date = trim($aGame->find('.datetime', 0)->plaintext);

    $html = file_get_contents($linkID);
    $titleList->load($html);

    $team1 =  $titleList->find('h3', 0)->plaintext;
    if (!$team1) {
      continue;
    }
    $team2 =  $titleList->find('h3', 1)->plaintext;

    $bestof = $titleList->find('.match-extras .bestof', 0)->plaintext;
    $bestof = current(array_slice(explode(' ', $bestof), 2, 1));
    if(!is_numeric($bestof)) $bestof = '?';

    $fullDate = $titleList->find('.match-extras .datetime', 0)->plaintext;
    $fullDate = str_replace("at", "", $fullDate);
    $fullDate = $fullDate . " CET";
    $timeStamp = strtotime($fullDate); 
    $game['team1'] = $team1; 
    $game['team2'] = $team2; 
    $game['fullDate'] = $fullDate;
    $game['liveIn'] = $date;

    $output["upcoming"][] = $game;
  }
  $str = json_encode($output);
    $filestr  = "hearthstone.json";
    $fp=@fopen($filestr, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fwrite($fp, "");
    fclose($fp);
    echo $str; 
?>
```

Comment: @Антон Созоненко, вот вы веб-разработчик. Что вам говорит такая строчка, как 403 Forbidden?

Comment: Что доступ запрещен!

Comment: @Антон Созоненко, именно. То есть, в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: @Etki ну как то обойти это можно?
Или  я вот прочитал, что через cURL можно, но я в нем слабак((  
Хотел попросить пример парсера с данной страницы.

Comment: @Антон Созоненко, так, вернемся на шаг назад. Откуда появляется это "доступ запрещен"?

Comment: $html = file_get_contents('http://www.gosugamers.net/hearthstone/gosubet');

когда доходит до этого места!

Comment: @Антон Созоненко, нет, оно появляется, потому что веб-приложение на том конце запретило доступ вашему. Следовательно, вам нужно менять не транспорт, а разобраться, за что ваш айпишник получил бан и как его снять.

Comment: @Etki а как это решить) Я даже не знаю, куда думать =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот cURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.gosugamers.net/hearthstone/gosubet");
$ch = curl_exec($ch);
```